# Python keylistener - Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, keylistener, raspberry-pi

I have just got my raspberry pi and make it pulse a speaker :). Now I want it to make different sounds depending on what key you press. How do I implement a key listener in python the? I know how to do it in java, but not python :/. If you're wondering I am on a distro of linux and do have python installed etc. and I can't imagine it being different on any other linux system (maybe a different library for windows).

Also I am just running it from LXTerminal, so when I do type since the focus is set to the terminal I just end up typing in the terminal window. I tried this, but with no luck:

```
import Tkinter as tk
def keypress(event):
    x = event.char
```

Any ideas? I'd really appreciate it :)

Comment: Did you bind the handler to an event?

Comment: I did 'root = tk.Tk()' and coe other stuff like 'root.mainloop' or soething. I just copeid out of another forum, but I a not sure how to get it working. How would I bind it?

Comment: Here is the link I used: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/115282/get-key-press#

Comment: I have added 'root.bind_all('<key>' , keypress) and it seems to make no difference I am also using the Pis GPIO ports and when ever I use the Tkinter I cannot get any GPI activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this [link](https://github.com/dxs/UGV/blob/master/Python/gui_1.1.py), there is a complete code that works on the raspberry pi. Take some part of it and you will get your keyListener. Just before you lauch your code, make sure that you have typed `xset r off` into the terminal. Like that, you won't have any key repetition.